# vue js use npm module as inline script

Tags: vue.js

I am not using webpack, I include vue as external script Something like this:

```
<script src ="unpckg.com/vue.js-latest"></script>
```

And I want to use npm module

https://github.com/stephan281094/vue-drag-select

So I include it like this:

```
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/vue-drag-select@0.1.5/dist/vue-drag-select.js
"></script>
```

How do I use it?

UPD: I corrected the path to external script.

My question is how to include `vue-drag-select` component in my app because 
When I write

```
import DragSelect from 'vue-drag-select/src/DragSelect.vue'
```

It gives me an error because I don't use webpack, so there is no import function

Comment: You can use jsdelivr https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/vue-drag-select `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-drag-select@0.1.5/dist/vue-drag-select.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @ittus see upd..

Answer (score 0):

This is just a url `https://github.com/stephan281094/vue-drag-select` to dispaly package details not any file path

Here is the raw data of `.js` file might be you want to include, go this url and save contents of this file in your local and then import/include

```
https://github.com/stephan281094/vue-drag-select/blob/master/dist/vue-drag-select.js
```

Comment: see an update. I understand how to include local file of file from npm or src. I cannot use import / include because I am not using webpack

Answer (score 0):

If you include cdn script, then DragSelect is global variable, you can access it directly

```
Vue.component('vue-drag-select', DragSelect.default)
```

```js
Vue.component('vue-drag-select', DragSelect.default)
new Vue({
  el: "#app1",
  methods: {
    getClasses (item, selectedItems) {
      const isActive = !!(selectedItems.find((selectedItem) => {
        return parseInt(selectedItem.dataset.item, 10) === item
      }))
      return {
        item: true,
        active: isActive
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
*,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    user-select: none;
  }
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
  body {
    font: 16px / 1.5 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    padding: 5%;
  }
  /* Custom styling */
  .item {
    display: inline-flex;
    min-width: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .item.active {
    background-color: rgb(0, 162, 255);
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-drag-select@0.1.5/dist/vue-drag-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>


  <div id="app1">
    <h1>Vue Drag Select Example</h1>
      <vue-drag-select selector-class="item">
        <template slot-scope="{ selectedItems }">
          <div
            v-for="item in 50"
            :class="getClasses(item, selectedItems)"
            :data-item="item"
          >
            Item {{ item }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </vue-drag-select>
  </div>
```